# Boolean operators and parentheses

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Can someone explain to me why this is returning false? All of these statements should be true, except for the one with `OR` statements - so it should be fine, yet it returns false when I run it.

```
c1 = 2;
c2 = 2; 
row = 3;
column = 2;

if ((c2 < 3) && (row == c1++) && ((column == c2) || (column == c2++))){
    return true;
```

Comment: Try printing each condition. Or use a debugger.

Comment: Note that the vast majority of those `()` serve no purpose at all. That condition is equivalent to `if (c2 < 3 && row == c1++ && (column == c2 || column == c2++)){`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row == c1++` is false since post increment operator returns the previous value of the incremented variable. This means your are checking if 3 == 2, which is false.

If you switch to pre-increment, you'll get true:

```
if ((c2 < 3) && (row == ++c1) && ((column == c2) || (column == c2++))) {
    return true;
}
```

BTW, you can simply write

```
return (c2 < 3) && (row == ++c1) && ((column == c2) || (column == c2++));
```

instead of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here `row == c1++` and `column == c2++`, you are using post increment.
It means that `c1` and `c2` are incremented only after the execution of the statement.

You can use the pre increment operator so that the increment be effective before the next statement.

Replace  `row == c1++` and `column == c2++` by 
 `row == ++c1` and `column == ++c2`

Answer (score 1):

```
((c2 < 3) && (row == c1++) && ((column == c2) || (column == c2++)))
//   1            2                     3a             3b
```

(1) `c2 < 3` => `2 < 3` => `true`

(2) `row == c1++` => `3 == 2` (use and change - post increment) => `false`

No further evaluations are made, since (2) has been determined to be `false`, and the resultant expression is `false`. This is a consequence of conditional expression shorcircuiting.